# How can I deploy a Python script to Heroku for performing dynamic sum, division and multiplication on-demand?

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy a script to Heroku that for example, returns a sum, division and multiplication of two numbers that are dynamically passed.

script.py

```
def sum(a, b):
    ans = a+b
    print(ans)
    return ans

def  mul(a, b):
    ans = a*b
    print(ans)
    return ans

def div(a, b):
    ans = a/b
    print(ans)
    return ans
```

I would like this script to be called on demand and also specify the function that I would like to call by passing the parameters. I am fairly new to Heroku so any advice is a plus. Is this possible in Heroku? If not, what other platforms should I be looking at?

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You will more than likely need some sort of web framework to do this. Flask is easy to use and implement. You could just set up a few endpoints for each different function you want to call and then just return the value. Something like below.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sum')
def sum():
    a = int(request.args.get('a'))
    b = int(request.args.get('b'))
    ans = a+b
    print(ans)
    return jsonify(ans)

@app.route('/mul')
def  mul():
    a = int(request.args.get('a'))
    b = int(request.args.get('b'))
    ans = a*b
    print(ans)
    return jsonify(ans)

@app.route('/div')
def div():
    a = int(request.args.get('a'))
    b = int(request.args.get('b'))
    ans = a/b
    print(ans)
    return jsonify(ans)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


# Parameters (a & b) can be passed as url params like so
# http://127.0.0.1:5000/mul?a=1&b=2
```

Heroku has good documentation on how to go about deploying a Python app like this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python